# Multiple Currency symbols in numberformatinfo

Tags: c#, localization, number-formatting, cultureinfo

While writing a piece of code, I came across where using `Numberformatinfo`, I had to write two currency symbols for a country at the same time.

Taiwan, now uses `TWD` as their currency symbol along with `起`. So they write their Currency as `NTD 23,900 起`.

But just by using NumberformatInfo, I am not able to put two currency symbols at the same time.

```
    public NumberFormatInfo GetCurrencyFormat(string countryCode, string languageCode)
    {var cultureInfo = GetCultureInfo(countryCode, languageCode);

        var currencyFormat = GetCurrencyFormat(cultureInfo);
        return currencyFormat;
    }
```

Here I can change the symbol, but to only one of the above mentioned, which can be placed either before the amount or after.

Comment: There ssems to be even more problems with culture info. See this post *(including comments and answers)*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926486/what-controls-the-currencypositivepattern-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, there is only one way, how to do this. You need to implement a custom type with a custom formatter.

There seems not be a support for two currency symbols/shortcuts and or one of four predefined formats *(see: [remarks in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern?view=netframework-4.7.2))*

Simple version can be like this.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace TwoCurrencySymbols
{
  internal sealed class Currency : IFormattable
  {
    private readonly IFormattable value;

    public Currency(IFormattable myValue)
    {
      value = myValue;
    }

    public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
      if (format == "C")
      {
        return ("EUR " + value.ToString(format, formatProvider));
      }

      return value.ToString(format, formatProvider);
    }
  }

  internal static class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C}", new Currency(1)));
    }
  }
}
```

The example is constructed for EURO currency *(my locale)*. In your real implementation you need to determine, whether the format should be changed, e.g. if `if ((format == "C") && IsTaiwan(formatProvider))`.

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped you. Unfortunately I had no time to make a better example. I'm afraid that the country detection is not that simple from format provider only. And there is also a problem with specific formats like `C2`.