# Currency symbol on wrong side

Tags: c#, .net, currency, cultureinfo

A price is being displayed in a `RichTextBox`. It takes a `double` value representing the price and displays it as a string.

```
double priceDisplayed = 0.00;
richTextBox_itemPrice.Text = priceDisplayed.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-AU"));
```

The above code results in the price being displayed with the currency on the RHS:

```
0.00$
```

Why is this? Checking similar examples, it seems the code above should show the currency symbol on the LHS.

Comment: Will rendering the text to a string variable before assigning to richTextBox_itemPrice.Text fix the issue?

Comment: Renders as `$0.00` for me in dot net fiddle. Can you provide any more information about the execution environment?

Comment: @Gavin, I tried that, same issue.

Comment: @IanMercer this is a WinForms app targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1. Tried both Debug and Release builds. Built with VS 2017, running on Windows 10.

Comment: What's your `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` and `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name`?  I have a feeling one of them is affecting the result of your formatting.

Comment: @NPras, "en-AU" and "en-US", respectively.

Comment: That's *really* weird. Is your `new CultureInfo("en-AU").NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern` anything other than 0? ([it should be 0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern?view=netframework-4.7.2) especially considering your current culture..) There's a similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474907/5623232) with different frameworks and machines, maybe try using `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-AU")`?

Comment: @NPras, after trying your suggestions, the problem still remains.

Comment: I'm as baffled as you are, also running on en-AU. Do you have another machine to test the app on? This has got to be machine-specific..

Comment: Have you tried to put the result in a string and check the string? Just to make sure the edit box isn't screwing with the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really strange, as mentioned in the comment, there must be some *culture*-clashes on your machine.

In the meantime, you could try something like this on the event `TextChanged`:

```
private void richTextBox_itemPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = richTextBox_itemPrice.Text;
    if (richTextBox_itemPrice.Text.Contains("$")) 
    {
        text = text.Replace("$","");
    }

    richTextBox_itemPrice.Text = "$" + text;
}
```

And initialize the field to have `richTextBox_itemPrice.Text = "$";`